# How can I use nginx 1.9.5 as a reverse proxy with gRPC?

Tags: nginx, proxy, grpc, grpc-java

I want to

- write my backend code with Java,
- use HTTP/2 (NGINX 1.9.5 has been supported HTTP/2),
- write a bidirectional stream to send data between client and server at any time.

**gRPC** seems to be the best choice and I want use **NGINX** as my reverse proxy and loading balancing, I could not find any documentation to figure out how to use NGINX with gRPC Java, does anyone know?

---

I saw the gRPC PHP has already supported NGINX: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/php#use-the-grpc-php-extension-with-nginxphp-fpm

But I also saw there is [an issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc.github.io/issues/230#issuecomment-244508727) said it is in the process of submitting a 3rd party module in NGINX for gRPC support, and there is [a ticket](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/923) on NGINX means we can't write HTTP/2 NGINX proxy module for gRPC, and I also saw [nginx does not support the full HTTP/2 specs, gRPC does not work through it](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/53syvy/grpc_envoy_nghttp2_and_load_balancing/)

I'm confused about that, why do some posts say gRPC PHP works but in other posts it says it can't.

Comment: gRPC has been added in 1.13.10 for those interested: https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-13-10-grpc/

Answer (score 4):

Not on nginx, but I just published a [grpc-proxy](https://github.com/devsu/grpc-proxy) written in Go. It's lightweight and configurable, and there is a [docker image](https://github.com/devsu/docker-grpc-proxy) available.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, nowdays, gRPC/HTTP2 with or without TLS are indeed fully supported on NGINX, as long as you have version 1.13.9 (if you just install the docker image with either alpine or latest tags then it'll be the right version).

As of (at least) late 2020 there is full support for it. Here's a link to their official Documentation:

https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-13-10-grpc/

Comment: To be honest, it's really not that different/complicated - I am trying to use mine as an API Gateway because Spring Cloud Modules like Netflix Zuul and Spring Cloud Gateway STILL can't support both HTTP/2 or gRPC forwarding in early 2021 - which is a disappointment because they have many other good features and are much less hassle to configure....

Comment: Here's a GitHub Issue on it - in case there are any future updates to this - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/40